# The Timer with TimerCallback and TimeSpan parameter is not calling the callback cyclically

Tags: c#, timer, callback, timespan, .net-4.7.2

Knowing well that Windows is not a real time OS I need to call a function cyclically in a very short time-span below 1 millisecond (*Requirement*). To avoid a higher CPU load, I felt good about using a `System.Threading.Timer` and a `TimerCallback` instead of using `Thread.Sleep` in an infinitiy-loop. This actually works fine in case the cycle-time is 1ms and above. However, going just 1 microsecond below leads to the fact that the `TimerCallback` is called only once.

I have here an example Code where this phenomena is reproducible.

Working example - cyclically with time-span of 1ms ~ 10000 ticks.
Setting a breakpoint at the `TimerCallBack` function one can see that it is called cyclically.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer( new TimerCallback(TimerCallBack), null,  TimeSpan.Zero, new TimeSpan(10000));
            Console.Read();
            timer.Dispose();
        }

        public static void TimerCallBack(object o)
        {
            Console.Write(".");
        }
    }
}
```

In contrast the following issue-example. Setting the breakpoint at the `TimerCallBack` function it is clear to see, that it is called only once. But why?

Issue example - time-span of 9999 ticks and callback is for whatever reason only called once.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer( new TimerCallback(TimerCallBack), null,  TimeSpan.Zero, new TimeSpan(9999));
            Console.Read();
            timer.Dispose();
        }

        public static void TimerCallBack(object o)
        {
            Console.Write(".");
        }
    }
}
```

How does it come to this situation with a value of 9999 so that the callback is not called cyclically anymore?

Is there a better solution or workaround?

.NET Framework 4.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to [reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/owNiOo) your observations. [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/28c7eb85636d8c97d44b0a619d59eb98ba0b98e3/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Timer.cs#L833) is the source code (simplified) of the `System.Threading.Timer` constructor that has two `TimeSpan` parameters:

```
public Timer(TimerCallback callback,
    object? state,
    TimeSpan dueTime,
    TimeSpan period)
{
    long dueTm = (long)dueTime.TotalMilliseconds;
    long periodTm = (long)period.TotalMilliseconds;
    TimerSetup(callback, state, (uint)dueTm, (uint)periodTm);
}
```

As you can see, only the milliseconds of the `TimeSpan`s are used. Any finer detail is rounded down to the nearest integer millisecond, which in your case is zero. And according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.-ctor):

> If `period` is zero (0) or negative one (-1) milliseconds and `dueTime` is positive, `callback` is invoked once; the periodic behavior of the timer is disabled, but can be re-enabled using the `Change` method.

You could consider clicking the "Edit this document" button near the top of the documentation page (it has the icon of a pencil), add a few words to clarify this behavior, and submit a PR to the [dotnet/dotnet-api-docs](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs) repository.